# Failed to set ConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy to All in Debezium mysql connector in docker

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Trying to set ConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy, by adding CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY=All. During start up debezium connector fails with **matches all=All**. Seems, CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY duplicates value, instead "All", value is "all=All"

```
Stopping due to error   [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements interface org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.ConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy and which name matches all=All
```

Is it bug or I am doing something wrong?

Using debezium docker 1.5

Answer (score 2):

this is partly bug and partly misconfiguration.
The env var should be named `CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY=All`

But at the same time the start script that processes all env vars named `CONNECT_` does not check for the underscore so `CONNECTOR...` matches too which breaks the further logic.